# Css percentage value in PHP

Tags: php, html, css

I'm trying to display results as a percentage bar (css), I get `$row['Balai']` from `mysql query`, then count the `$proc` of it, I set `$sum` as well. It's works fine, but instead of getting different `inner` value(bar) I always get the same and all the bars looks the same

```
while($row=$list->fetch_assoc()){
    $proc = round((($row['Balai'] / $sum) * 100),1); ?>
    <style type="text/CSS">
    .outter{
    height 25px;
    width:500px;
    border-right:solid 1px #000;
    background-color: red;
    }
    .inner{
    height:25px;
    width: <?php echo $proc ?>%;
    border-right:solid 1px #000;
    background-color:lightblue;
    </style>
    <tr>
    <center>
    <?php
    echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Vardas'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Pavarde'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Balai'] . "<td>"; ?>
    <div class="outter">
    <div class='inner'><?php echo $proc ?>%</div>
    <?php
    echo "</td><br />";
    echo "</center>";
    echo "</tr>";
    $x++;
    }
    echo "</table>";
    echo "<b>100% sudaro: " . $sum . "</b>";
```

Comment: Since the browser cannot see the PHP code you used to generate your HTML and CSS you could start diagnose by looking at the same code your browser sees. It's the *View Source* feature, often mapped to the Ctrl+U short-cut.

Comment: @Dr. Docttor break the table html structure. div should be inner part of the td/th tag only

Comment: Have you tried this statically? With a hard coded width?

Comment: @Doug, yes I did. It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Try this:(Please ensure the value of `$proc` is different)

```
 <style type="text/CSS">
        .outter{
        height 25px;
        width:500px;
        border-right:solid 1px #000;
        background-color: red;
        }
        .inner{
        height:25px;       
        border-right:solid 1px #000;
        background-color:lightblue;
        </style>
  <?php  
    while($row=$list->fetch_assoc()){
        $proc = round((($row['Balai'] / $sum) * 100),1); ?>

        <tr>
        <center>
        <?php
        echo "<td>" . $row['ID'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Vardas'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Pavarde'] . "</td><td>" . $row['Balai'] . "<td>"; ?>
        <div class="outter">
        <div class='inner' style='width: "<?php echo $proc ?>"%'><?php echo $proc ?>%</div>
        <?php
        echo "</td><br />";
        echo "</center>";
        echo "</tr>";
        $x++;
        }
        echo "</table>";
        echo "<b>100% sudaro: " . $sum . "</b>";
```

Comment: Still the same, and yes yech value that is echo'ed is different.

Comment: I have updated the code.Also from view source please check what is the width value

Comment: http://i68.tinypic.com/2ch24gn.png
Inspect element shows: http://i66.tinypic.com/2hga7bp.png
Seems like width changes, but not visually

Comment: LOL, I found the solution. You dont need double quotes when writting php code in div....